# Value of optional type 'BTAPIClient?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'BTAPIClient'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, paypal-sandbox

I am using official tutorial of Paypal-Braintree for payment gateaway.

I followed the tutorial still gives error.

My viewcontroller code with error -

```
   import UIKit
    import Braintree
    
     class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var braintreeClient: BTAPIClient?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Example: Initialize BTAPIClient, if you haven't already
    braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: "sandbox_bnkgmk59_5dxr37xvb54mg8sp ")
 
       }

      @IBAction func clickedBtnPay(_ sender: Any) {
      let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient:braintreeClient) ***/*Error - i) Value of optional type 'BTAPIClient?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'BTAPIClient'
```

ii)Coalesce using '??' to provide a default when the optional value contains 'nil'
iii) Force-unwrap using '!' to abort execution if the optional value contains 'nil'*/***

```
            payPalDriver.viewControllerPresentingDelegate = self
            payPalDriver.appSwitchDelegate = self // Optional
    // Specify the transaction amount here. "2.32" is used in this example.
    let request = BTPayPalRequest(amount: "2.32")
    request.currencyCode = "USD" // Optional; see BTPayPalRequest.h for more options

    payPalDriver.requestOneTimePayment(request) { (tokenizedPayPalAccount, error) in
        if let tokenizedPayPalAccount = tokenizedPayPalAccount {
            print("Got a nonce: \(tokenizedPayPalAccount.nonce)")

            // Access additional information
            let email = tokenizedPayPalAccount.email
            let firstName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.firstName
            let lastName = tokenizedPayPalAccount.lastName
            let phone = tokenizedPayPalAccount.phone

            // See BTPostalAddress.h for details
            let billingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.billingAddress
            let shippingAddress = tokenizedPayPalAccount.shippingAddress
        } else if let error = error {
            // Handle error here...
        } else {
            // Buyer canceled payment approval
        }


}
  }
     }
    extension MyViewController:BTViewControllerPresentingDelegate{
    func paymentDriver(_ driver: Any, requestsPresentationOf viewController:     UIViewController) {
    
     }
  
     func paymentDriver(_ driver: Any, requestsDismissalOf viewController: UIViewController) {
    
         }
     }

  extension MyViewController: BTAppSwitchDelegate {
   func appSwitcherWillPerformAppSwitch(_ appSwitcher: Any) {
    
}

func appSwitcher(_ appSwitcher: Any, didPerformSwitchTo target: BTAppSwitchTarget) {
    
}

func appSwitcherWillProcessPaymentInfo(_ appSwitcher: Any) {
    
   }
  }
```

When I follow the suggestions mentioned in the errors, it shows further error. How to sort it out ?

Comment: Hard to say if you don't show how you modify code in IBAction.

Comment: Error is quite clear, you can’t pass an optional value to that function. You need to unwrap it first using `if let` or `guard let`

Comment: when i add an exclamation mark, the build succeeds - "let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient:braintreeClient!)", but when i press the button it shows errors  i) Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. ii) the xcode console shows error - " [BraintreeSDK] ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid"

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 silly mistakes here -
i)when i add an exclamation mark, the build succeeds - "let payPalDriver = BTPayPalDriver(apiClient:braintreeClient!)"
ii)the xcode console showed error - " [BraintreeSDK] ERROR BTClient could not initialize because the provided clientToken was invalid" –
what I had not done was left a blank apace in the key - i had done  - braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: "sandbox_bsdfsfdfsg59_5dfgxr37xvb54mg8sp    ") i.e. blank space after the key. I rectified it i.e. -braintreeClient = BTAPIClient(authorization: "sandbox_bsdfsfdfsg59_5dfgxr37xvb54mg8sp") - no blank space and everything went smooth.